# How to stop abandonment cart emails to get fired when restoring quote data in cart page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, abandoned-cart

I am facing an issue after restoring Quote items on the cart page.

For restoring Quote I used below code

```
 $this->_checkoutSession->restoreQuote();
```

I have abandonment cart email functionality, but the dis-advantage is as soon as cart items are restored it fires abandonment cart email.

How can I stop this? Any advice is appreciated.